# A sentence without a subject — is it an imperative? "…be as useless and boring as a gray rock"

Tags: sentence-construction, imperative-sentences

> It’s exactly what it sounds like—be as useless and boring as a gray rock.

[source](https://www.wikihow.com/Confuse-a-Narcissist)

I was confused when I read this sentence. In my opinion, there should be a subject before the word 'be'. But there is nothing in here. So I guess it is an imperative sentence. If my idea is incorrect, please correct me.

Comment: Obviously an imperative.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly it looks like an imperative. The proof comes from glancing at the original page, *11 Ways to Confuse and Disarm a Narcissist.* Each of the 11 items is phrased as an imperative. Item 4 is *Bore them with the “gray rock” treatment*—an imperative. The first sentence of the item is the one you have quoted. It is simply a restatement of the item itself. We should not be surprised that it is also an imperative.